# VisualSVN - svn status Error W155007

Tags: svn

I'm trying to write a post-commit hook that will zip all the changed files saving the directory tree. When I try to do a `svn status` on a repository directory (with conf, db, hooks directories etc.), it outputs the `W155007` error saying this directory `is not a working copy`. I cannot afford to clone the repo locally just for zipping because repository size can exceed 1TB.

What am I doing wrong and is there an example for such a hook that can be run on Windows Server machine?

Comment: You don't need to archive every single revision in a post-commit hook. I don't know what's your idea or what's the problem you are trying to solve, but the proposed solution is wrong.

Comment: @bahrep The problem I'm solving is storing all the commits (new/deleted/modified files) in zips (to ease the download process) and then using my software to compare the local/online versions to download all the commit zips that are newer than a local revision. This needs to be done strictly using VisualSVN as a host (without spending half a year writing a similar program to already existing)

Comment: the server has a web interface that supports downloading files and folders. Click the Download button when needed and you will download file or directory as it was in a certain revision (you can open any earlier revision). The directory will be downloaded as a ZIP file. I think that you don't even need zips - you can script the svn.exe client to compare the versions. SVN is a version control system after all. It's all about storing and comparing versions of data. Right now it just looks like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @bahrep I cannot use the front-end web interface from C# code. Everything I need to do is to get any revision from a specific repo as one file. Speaking of svn.exe - I cannot afford to include it in every client installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong

A lot of:

1. You try (as you saw) to use command(s), designed to work with WC, for manipulating *repository as files*
2. You miss one details additionally - even in (clean after commit) WC `svn st` return nothing, because WC is clean
3. If you want to sync some non-versioned tree with the state of HEAD and have *functional state* of export, you **must take into account** and process the status of not only "changed" files, but at least "new" too and ideally also "deleted"

In any case, you have to learn [svnlook subcommands](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.html) and build (before using) reliable workflow

- which revision from repo to use
- how to get this rev-id
- consider building file-list in pre-commit hook and only use it in post-commit

and toolchain around it. Read about [svnlook changed](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html) for getting files, maybe [svnlook youngest](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.youngest.html) for getting revision for `changed` subcommand, if you'll work in post-commit only and will want always get files from last commit (beware of commits to WIP-branches)

Comment: So, I can use the svnlook changed command to view the differences in a specific revision, then export all this changes myself and zip them? (considering every repo has strictly one branch, no rollbacks are ever done and a list of deleted files will be stored in a different text file that will be parsed on the client-side)

Comment: @GettingPleasure - well, "yes" in common